# Why isn't this prime factors thing working?

Tags: javascript

```
function prime(number) {
    var primeNumbers = [];
    var numberDivide = 2;
    for(var i=0; i<number; i++) {
        var nice = number/numberDivide;
        if(Math.floor(nice) == nice) {
            number = nice;
            primeNumbers.push(numberDivide);
        } else {
            numberDivide++
        }
        console.log(primeNumbers)
    }
}
```

That is my code. It is not logging the final prime number, I don't know why. I went through and spoke it out loud but it isn't working...

Comment: Are you ever calling the function? If yes, with what values does it not work?

Comment: Well, you only iterate over the number and try to divide it a set amount of times. Presumably, you might reach the last loop, but it falls into the `else` clause, increases `numberDivide` and...never divides by the new value.

Comment: Are you sure you want to overwrite the `number` variable? Can you tell us what you have spoken aloud so we can find the flaw in your reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

First a code translation that works with integers to see what the function is doing:

```
function prime(number) {
    var primeNumbers = [];

    for(var divisor =2; divisor <= number;){
        if( number % divisor == 0){
            primeNumbers.push(divisor);
            number = number/divisor;
            continue;
        }
        ++divisor;
     }
    return primeNumbers;
}

console.log(    prime(18));  // returns [2,3,3]
```

Here `number` is replaced by the quotient of dividing it by a prime factor to see if additional prime factors can be found over and above those determined already. Note that `number` keeps getting smaller, and `dividend` is not incremented when found to be a factor so the next loop can test if it is a multiple factor.

*So how many times does the loop iterate?* This version doesn't count them, but the posted version stops iterating when the loop counter (not otherwise used) is greater or equal to `number` which as discussed keeps getting smaller.

The posted function fails for `prime(18)` and returns [2,3] instead of [2,3,3]. If it is allowed to iterate one more time it produces the correct result. I haven't looked into pre-calculating how many times to loop, but the method of finding when to exit the loop in the posted code is the cause of the problem.